# Sending messages with mpi

Tags: c, mpi

I need some help here. I have a mpi program, that just send and receive messages. But the program don't work correctly.I read and saw another examples and i think that my program have to work.When the program run, the messages are send but the program doesn't finish. It's seem like it would be waiting for something.Here is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<mpi.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
int this_proc, total_procs;


MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &total_procs );
MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &this_proc );



int i;
int* localI;
localI=(int*)malloc(sizeof(double));

if (this_proc != 0)
{
    MPI_Send(&this_proc, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("Enviado %d\n",this_proc );
}
else
{
    for (i = 1; i < total_procs; i++)
    {
        MPI_Recv(localI, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        printf("Recibiendo mensaje del proceso nro %d \n", *localI);
     }

    // This is only called for the process that enters the else block

}
MPI_Finalize();
printf("Finalizando %d\n", this_proc);
}
```

I run my program for 5 process

> mpirun -np 5 holaMundo

The output is the next:

> ```
> Recibiendo mensaje del proceso nro 1 
> Recibiendo mensaje del proceso nro 2 
> Recibiendo mensaje del proceso nro 3  
> Recibiendo mensaje del proceso nro 4
> ```

Like you can see the program doesn't finish.
I think it have work...
Thank for your help and sorry for my english again.

Comment: your program does not compile. fix indentation first, and then the program.

Answer (score 2):

[MPI_Finalize: "All processes must call this routine before exiting"](http://www.open-mpi.de/doc/v2.0/man3/MPI_Finalize.3.php)

Your code with better indention looks as follows:

```
if (this_proc != 0)
{
    MPI_Send(&this_proc, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
else
{
    for (i = 1; i < total_procs; i++)
    {
        MPI_Recv(localI, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        printf("Recibiendo mensaje del proceso nro %d \n", *localI);
    }

    // This is only called for the process that enters the else block
    MPI_Finalize();
    printf("Finalizando %d\n", this_proc);
}
```

See my added comment at `MPI_Finalize`.

Comment: Well that was a mistake. But I already corrected that error and the output remains the same. The program does not end, does not show any "Finishing #" message. My code looks like your code now, and it doesn't work. Sorry but i don't underestand why.

Comment: @Patricio please edit the question with updated code... your code should NOT look like mine, I merely pointed out the error instead of fixing it. If you understand the quoted documentation and understand what's happening, then you will be able to fix it.

Comment: the code is updated. maybe I did not express myself correctly. I correcred the code. Now all the process finish their execution.